# How to get the services details using the python paramiko module from the remote server

Tags: python, paramiko

I want to get the details of the service using the paramiko module.

Using the below code snippet:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
cmd='systemctl status docker'
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)

print(stdout.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

The [exec_command](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) is a non-blocking call. So you have to wait for completion of the remote command.

> Execute a command on the SSH server. A new Channel is opened and the
>   requested command is executed. The command’s input and output streams
>   are returned as Python file-like objects representing stdin, stdout,
>   and stderr.

So if you want to get the output try:

```
return_code = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
```

The [recv_exit_status](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status) will block until the comand finish, this way you will also get the return code of the commad itself.

> Return the exit status from the process on the server. This is mostly
>   useful for retrieving the results of an exec_command. If the command
>   hasn’t finished yet, this method will wait until it does, or until the
>   channel is closed. If no exit status is provided by the server, -1 is
>   returned.